# Excluding some parameter regions from the plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am plotting the numerical solutions of the following

```
eq[α_, k_, x_] := Sin[k + α] + k Sin[k] == x*Cos[k]
   y = sol[x_?NumericQ, k_ /; 0 <= k <= Pi] := α /. 
   NSolve[{eq[α, k, x], 0 <= α <= Pi}, α, Reals]
Manipulate[ContourPlot[Evaluate[eq[α, k, x]], {α, 0, Pi}, {k, -Pi, Pi}], 
 {{x,1}, 0, 10, .01}]
```

There are regions where I have two solutions and regions where I have one e.g., `sol[1, 0.1]` returns two solutions, `sol[2,0.1]` has no solution, `sol[0.1,0.1]` has one solution and so on. Is it possible to exclude say two solutions regime say `sol[1, 0.1]` i.e., excluding `x=1,k=0.1` and plotting for the rest of the parameters, and is it also implementable to exclude more than one such parameter ranges e.g., `sol[1,0.1]`,`sol[1,0.2]`?

Comment: Check out plotting the followig function over `x` ans `k`: `sol[x_?NumericQ, k_ /; 0 <= k <= Pi] := 
 With[{sols = 
    NSolve[{eq[\[Alpha], k, x], 0 <= \[Alpha] <= Pi}, \[Alpha], 
     Reals]},
  If[Length[sols] == 1, \[Alpha] /. 
    NSolve[{eq[\[Alpha], k, x], 0 <= \[Alpha] <= Pi}, \[Alpha], 
     Reals], {}]
  ]` with `Plot3D[sol[x, k], {k, -Pi, Pi}, {x, 0, 2}]`. Is that whay you want?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher this is perfect, Thanks. It allows to consider only specific solutions with the `Length` command. Do I need to also care about the parameter range with this command? like e.g., plotting for `x=0` to `x=2` with `Length[sols] == 1` and `Length[sols] == 2` will automatically pick up the relevant solutions to plot even if in some ranges there are no solutions satisfying this condition, like `sol[2,0.1]` has no solution so this did not return any error.